# Decreasing size of PDF when using puppeteer for pdf generation

Tags: pdf, puppeteer, html-to-pdf, pdf-to-html

We are using IDR for converting PDF documents to HTML.

After doing some modifications we are using puppeteer for converting that document back to PDF I am getting files with increased page size (even if I don't do any modification to my HTML).

For ex:- If the original page size is 500kb I am getting a page with 1000kb

The page only contains some text.

Please help me to understand what is the reason behind this and how to solve this.

Comment: did u solve this ?

Comment: I have drastically reduced the PDF size by resizing the images and other components that goes into the html page which in turn will be converted into a pdf. Also use as much as the canvas elements for designing.